# how to delete all files related to k8s

Tags: kubernetes

I had configured multi master of k8s repeatedly.
It looks like the previous configuration of master held still.
The pod of calico node didn't work properly.

I want to remove all files of k8s.
Could you know how to remove the all files ?

Comment: used kubeadm or something else to setup the cluster?

Comment: It's local, On-Prem? What OS did you use and what version of Kubectl, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Many depends how did you create cluster.

If you used `Kubeadm` you can use [kubeadm reset](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-reset/) which will revert of changes made by `kubeadm init` or `kubeadm join`.

Beside that you need to delete `kubectl`, `kubeadm`, etc. If you instlled it using `apt-get` (depends on distro. This is example from ubuntu) you can `purge` them.

```
$ sudo apt-get purge kubeadm kubectl kube*
```

Then use `autoremove` to get rid out of all dependencies related.

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
```

And at the end you should remove rest of config using:

- **$ sudo rm -rf ~/.kube**
- **ipvsadm --clear** or **iptables -F && iptables -t nat -F && iptables -t mangle -F && iptables -X** or similar to clean-up iptables rules

If this won't answer your question, please add more information about your cluster.